# Jquery popup menu no stick with header

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a right side button in my header. When click the button, a popup list menu will display. But when I scroll down the page, header is scroll down. But the popup menu is keep stick at top. How to I make popup menu stick with header? Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

    <style>
    </style>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">                 
            <h1>Chats</h1>
            <a id="chatpageicon"  href="#photopopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin"  data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" data-form="ui-icon"  data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-right  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-b" ></a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="photopopup">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:150px;position:fixed;right:30px;">
                    <li><a href="#">List1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">    
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
            <p>asd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Before scroll:
[image]

After scroll down, the popup menu still keep at same position:
[image]

How do I make it stick together with my header? Even scroll to the end. Thanks

**Updated:**

I edited my code (refer "Nisal Upendra" solution), the issue for second screen shot is fixed. But if I scroll down first, and click the header button. the menu is popup at middle of the screen as image as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `style="min-width:150px;position:fixed;right:30px;"`
 to your popup styling.
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hym405nz/1/

Comment: If i click popup first before scrolling is work, but if click popup after scroll first. The popup is run away.

Comment: it works, check this other fiddle. I checked this one.
http://jsfiddle.net/uoe8thcq/
Make sure you have all the frameworks and extensions inplace as in the fiddle.

Comment: I have edit my question and add a screen shot for my issue. Please review