# Hide jquery mobile popup when scrolling page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

A popup appear by click the header button, I want hide the popup automatically when scrolling the page, because the popup itself doesn't move when I scroll to bottom page currently. When I click anywhere of the page, it jump back to top. 
I have a code as below:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">                 
     <h1 class="strokeme">Home</h1>
     <a id="homepgicon"  href="#photopopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin"  data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" data-form="ui-icon"  data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-right  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-b" ></a>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="photopopup">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:250px;">
      <li><a href="index2.php" rel="external">Second Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So thinking if I hide the popup when detect page scrolling, the page won't jump back to the top page. Possible to make it?

My previous post with screen shot.
[Jquery popup menu no stick with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604991/jquery-popup-menu-no-stick-with-header/32605823?noredirect=1#comment53096046_32605823)

Comment: can we have you code in fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('#photopopup').is(":visible")){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('#photopopup').hide();
    });
}
```